# 文の組み立て Question about word order

Tags: grammar, word-order

I am having problems with some sentences in those JLPT problems where one has to assemble the sentence from 4 piece of text phrases.

The book contains the correct answer, but doesn't tell me the correct order of all elements. Are those sentences correct?

> - フリーターは労働市場で 「極めて」 「不利な」 「状況に」 「置かれ」 貧困に陥る可能性がある。
>     (#2 is known to be correct from the solution booklet)
> - この映画は、タイトルを見ると「その実は」「コメディの」「ようで」「いかにも」社会の矛盾を問うドキュメンタリーである。
>     (#3 is known to be correct from the solution booklet)

I struggle especially with the second sentence how to understand いかにも and その実は in this sentence.

Comment: Does the book really say いかんにも? That looks like a typo to me.

Comment: It is いかにも sorry

Comment: What does "#2" or "#3" refer to?

Comment: it means the 2nd expression in brackets in the first sentence and the 3rd expression in the second sentence are correctly placed. 
My question is if the other expressions are ordered correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1)『フリーターは[労働市場]{ろうどうしじょう}で 「[極]{きわ}めて」 「[不利]{ふり}な」 「[状況]{じょうきょう}に」 「[置]{お}かれ」 [貧困]{ひんこん}に[陥]{おちい}る[可能性]{かのうせい}がある。』

The four words/phrases are already in the correct order.

> 「フリーターは労働市場で極めて不利な状況に置かれ、貧困に陥る可能性がある。」
>
> "Part-timers are put in an extremely disadvantageous situation in the labor market, and they face a possibility of falling into poverty."

(I used the term "part-timers" for 「フリーター」, but many of them actually work full-time.  It is just that they are not "regular" or "permanent" employees.)

> 2)『この[映画]{えいが}は、タイトルを見ると「その[実]{じつ}は」「コメディの」「ようで」「いかにも」[社会]{しゃかい}の[矛盾]{むじゅん}を[問]{と}うドキュメンタリーである。』

makes no sense at all.  The sentence that makes sense would be:

> 『この映画は、タイトルを見ると 「いかにも」「コメディの」「ようで」、「その実は」 社会の矛盾を問うドキュメンタリーである。』
>
> "As for this movie, upon looking at its title, it indeed looks to be a comedy, but in reality, it is a documentary that inquires about social contradictions."

「いかにも」 means "indeed typically ~~", "surely representative of ~~", etc.

「その[実]{じつ}」 means "the reality of it", "the fact of the matter", etc.　Used when something is different from its appearance.